# Unable to install any package

Tags: apt, software-center, synaptic

When I try to install ANY application through terminal, I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (21: Is a directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

And software center is also not opening.

Neither is Synaptic Package Manager. It gives the following error when I try to open it:

```
E: Read error - read (21: Is a directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Solutions I tried so far, but didn't fix the problem:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Any suggestions? I cannot even use `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the whole `/var/lib/apt/lists` hierarchic, you must create the `partial` directory under it:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
```

Also, check that all the permissions are set:

```
sudo chmod -R 644 /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo chown -R root:root /var/lib/apt/lists
```

Then do `apt-get update` again.

Comment: hi braiam, This didn't solved my problem. let me know any other ways

Comment: please check my question
http://askubuntu.com/questions/363581/sudo-apt-get-check-gives-me-the-following-error