# sudo apt-get check gives me the following error

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

```
sudo apt-get check

Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (21: Is a directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What's the output of `ls /var/lib/apt/lists/`?

Comment: http://pastie.org/8420608 please check the above link for my output

Comment: Could you include the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/status`?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there are some mixed permissions and directories into the `/var/lib/apt/lists/` removing them and recreating should fix the issue:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

First command should nuke away the directory, second recreate the partial directory, third populate the lists files.

Comment: still i have the same error
krs@happy:~$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (21: Is a directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
krs@happy:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (21: Is a directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: Perhaps there's a problem with your file system. You could try using `fsck` to make sure you don't have file system corruption.

Comment: please let me know regarding fsck and what am i supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

Broken `/var`.
Check that `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is file but not directory. Else remake it like:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/status -d
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Next try

```
sudo dpkg -i apt
```

It realy not work but say about break directories.

In `/var/lib/dpkg/` should be  directories: `/alternatives, /info, /parts, /triggers, /updates`.

Comment: I am not following you drift, can you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: Sorry my English. I had the same problem when was broken directory /var. You can to try repair it as I wrote above. But there can many error. Will be better reinstall OS.

Comment: Please ask a fresh question with this issue.

Comment: no issues, it's answers